# How to show data only belonging to the user .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I am making a simple to-do application. I created MVC app using Individual User Authentication.
I created a table, named:- "Tasks" in the database and created Model in MVC using Et framework. Then I generated Controllers and Views to Edit , Delete and Details, using the table using Et framework.
My problem is, it shows all the tasks to all registered users.
What is the proper way to show only the tasks created by the logged in user?
Please redirect me to some example or provide me any hint.
Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your models and the controller and we can help you from there

Comment: Are you saving user id who created the task in database, if yes then filter the result with current user id

Comment: Get the ID of user on your action and load data on the basics of that ID

Comment: In this approach, I will have to put check every where. For example if someone deletes based on id then I will have to check whether this task id is belonging to the current logged in user. and I will have to put checks every where in all controllers and actions. Is there not a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used scaffold you might see something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
   return View(await _context.Tasks.ToListAsync());
}
```

Instead you can query the tasks:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
   var userTasks = await _context.Tasks.Where(t=>t.UserId == loggedInUserId).ToListAsync();
   return (userTasks);
}
```

Queries in LINQ to Entities

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/queries-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: In this approach, I will have to put check every where. For example if someone deletes based on id then I will have to check whether this task id is belonging to the current logged in user. and I will have to put checks every where in all controllers and actions. Is there not a proper way?